# slack-ruby-client: invalid_user with users_profile_set

Tags: ruby, slack-api

I've got **Slack::Web::Api::Error: invalid_user** with users_profile_set method. I have 2 users, and my find_user method (return response with user info) - works well for them. But if I want change status (the same for this cases) - for one user everything is correct, for the second - I've got this error.

Example of call users_profile_set method:

```
client.users_profile_set(user: find_user.id, profile: status.to_json)
```

My example status hash:

```
{:status_text=>"Remote - Today", :status_emoji=>":house_with_garden:"}
```

find_user:

```
client.users_list.members.find { |member| member.profile.email == user.email }
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option to change user's profile has only on the Paid Plans of Slack

Comment: You can change your *own* profile, if you are using an API token (now known as a "legacy API token") created by your user.  Just not someone else's.